# ListPreference: how to display without popup?

Tags: android

In my app's preferences there are some voices that are managed with ListPreference.
For example:

```
<ListPreference android:title="@string/pref_clear_buttons"
                android:summary="@string/pref_clear_buttons_summary"
                android:key="clear_buttons" android:defaultValue="right"
                android:entries="@array/buttons_entries" android:entryValues="@array/buttons_values"
                />
```

With entryValues taking the values of "hide", "left", "right".

When I run the preferences activity the ListPreference takes one single row, and when I click it opens a popup where I can choose among the three preferences, as if it was a sort of submenu.

[image]

I want all the three radio buttons to display indented, directly below the "Clear Buttons" line, without asking the user one extra click to open the popup.

Any easy idea?
Thank you.